# trying to create reusable append to struct in go

Tags: go

i am trying to make reusable method / func in go to push valu struct to another slice/ array in struct

i tried like this

```
import (
    "fmt"
)


type ErrorValidate struct {
    ErrorKey string 
    Message string  
}

type ValidateMessage struct {
     ErrorMessage []*ErrorValidate
}

func (v *ValidateMessage) AddError(err ErrorValidate) {
    v.ErrorMessage = append(v.ErrorMessage, &err)
}

func main() {
    s1 := *ValidateMessage{}
    s1.AddError(&ErrorValidate{"theKey", "string"})
    fmt.Println(*s1)
}
```

got error `invalid indirect of ValidateMessage literal (type ValidateMessage)`

the link here https://play.golang.org/p/VjdsiZQLroF

on those case i have a func for Validate something and then i tried to push error message on ErrorValidate , but i keep using append in my conditional, i am trying to make it reduce but got error above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems in your code. This one is generating your error (nothing to do with your append, or that method at all):

```
s1 := *ValidateMessage{}
```

This is not valid syntax. You probably meant `s1 := &ValidateMessage{}`.

```
s1.AddError(&ErrorValidate{"theKey", "string"})
```

You're trying to pass a `*ErrorValidate` to a function that takes a `ErrorValidate`. This should be `s1.AddError(ErrorValidate{"theKey", "string"})`.

Comment: when i try print it, the result is &{[0x40a0f0]}, any wrong ? i want to see what is inside the ValidateMessage{}

Comment: When you try to print what? Where? How?